# Change text and row colour on click

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have in my custom adapter these lines of code:

```
int colorPos = position % colours.length;
vi.setBackgroundColor(colours[colorPos]);
```

`colours` is defined like so:

```
private int[] colours = new int[] { R.drawable.row_colour, R.drawable.row_colour2 };
```

I use this so when the user clicks on one of my rows the background colours change. I have each row alternate colors so thats why there is two `R.drawable.row_colour`s. The initial colour is supposed to be grey but all the rows are black. And when i click on each row it goes to this brown colour. Here is my row_colour and row_colour2 code:

**row_colour**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:color="#ABCC2A" />
  <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#ABCC2A" />
  <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#ABCC2A" />
  <item android:color="#424242" />
</selector>
```

**row_colour2**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:color="#ABCC2A" />
  <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#ABCC2A" />
  <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#ABCC2A" />
  <item android:color="#1B1B1B" />
</selector>
```

I need to change the colour of the background but with this code its not working. I need the rows to alternate between `#424242` and `#1B1B1B` and when they are clicked go to `#ABCC2A`. Thanks in advance for any information you may provide

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the colour to change only momentarily when the user is pressing the item, just remove the state_focused elements, like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#ABCC2A" />
  <item android:color="#424242" />
</selector>
```

If, however, you want the colour to stay changed, you will need extend your adapter or list and store which item is selected, or extend the root layout of each item to store whether it is selected or not. Then, in your custom adapter, when supplying the views, query this information and modify the background colour to suit. All in all, a messy and complex way of achieving something that should supposedly be simple. I have heard that another method is to implement the Checkable interface in an extended root layout for your items, but have personally never had success with this.

Comment: that still doesn't work for my row background. It still comes up a brown colour. Also the main colour of the rows is all black when it is supposed to alternate between black and gray

Comment: When you say it goes to a brown colour, do you mean that the change when it is pressed is working, but it is going some brown colour rather than the greenish colour that is #ABCC2A? And are the row backgrounds currently black #000000, or the #1B1B1B that some are supposed to be?

Comment: The rows are currently black and yes it is going to some brownish instead of that green colour i want.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your color programmatically from the method getView in your adapter you have to update the state in your adapter...through a set method or whatever...and then call a function that forces your ListView to redraw its state, and consequently rebuild the list items by calling getView on the adapter. I tried ListView.invalidate() and it works but BaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() should work too.